# How to show drop down list in Angular to choose one item from MySQL table?

Tags: html, angular, dropdown

I have a database table `airline` and I want to show all data from the table in a `drop down list` and then to be able to choose one item from the list.

[image]

airline.ts

```
export class Airline {
  airline_id: number;
  name: string;
  symbol: string;
}
```

My HTML code, that doesn't work (only shows drop down list without data inside):

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Airlines" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="airline">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let airline of airlines" [value]="airline.name">
      {{airline.symbol}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Actually it looks like this (without data inside the list):

[image]

airlineService.ts

```
export class AirlineService {
    private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/airlines';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    getAirline(airline_id: number): Observable<Airline> {
        return this.http.get<Airline>(`${this.baseUrl}/${airline_id}`);
    }

    getAirlinesList(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`);
    }
}
```

airlines-list.component.ts

```
export class AirlinesListComponent implements OnInit {
    airlines: Observable<Airline[]>;
    airline_id: number;
    selectedValue: string;

    @Input() airline: Airline;

    constructor(private airlineService: AirlineService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.reloadData();
    }

    reloadData() {
        this.airlines = this.airlineService.getAirlinesList();
    }
}
```

Comment: `airlines` is an Observable. You may need to change the `ngFor` to something like this: `*ngFor="let airline of (airlines | async)"`

Comment: @R.Richards thank you, it works ;)

Comment: Nice post, by the way. Good to see that you only included the information that was really needed. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you declared the `airlines` variable as an Observable, you need to treat is as such when referring to it in the template.

Change your `ngFor` from this:

```
*ngFor="let airline of airlines"
```

to this:

```
*ngFor="let airline of (airlines | async)"
```